# Why are these two lines not congruent (and other ways to figure out if other shapes are not congruent)

Tags: geometry, triangles, congruences, formal-proofs

I stumbled apon this questions in a proofs worksheet and I was quite baffled by it because it seems like you can prove the sides to be congruent by cpctc however after I checked my work, the answers simply just said not necessarily.

So I was just hoping someone knew a way to figure out why the two sides were not congruent and is there another way besides AAA and ASS or SSA is there another way to prove that these two shapes are just not congruent.

Thanks (An answer with some work would be greatly appreciated)

QUESTION (Only 19 and 20):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mua1v.jpg

ANSWERS FOR 19 AND 20:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NttzS.png

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the diagram tells you where the point $A$ is on the lower line. What if it's way off to the left?

Comment: Oh ok, and also you can't also prove that triangles abc and bcd are congruent therefore there is no cpctc to make the sides congruent right? Can you prove ASS in any way?

Comment: You can't prove any congruence about a triangle containing $A$ since you don't know where $A$ is on the line.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply